# Which vantage point allows to see the Cristo Rendedor with Rio behind it?

Tags: rio-de-janeiro, viewpoint

While it is clear that there is a platform right at the Cristo Rendedor statue on Corcovado, from where one can see the statue up close or Rio, there seems to be quite a few images online taken further so that one can see the whole statue and Rio behind it:

[image]
[Source](https://www.civitatis.com/pt/rio-de-janeiro/visita-cristo-redentor/)

[image]
[Source](https://www.wheretraveler.com/rio-de-janeiro/cristo-redentor-christ-redeemer)

Is there accessible vantages point to get such a view? How does one get there? While I am certain some of these photos are taken by drones, there are a good number showing a very similar viewpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get this viewpoint while hovering in the air behind the statue. There *are* higher mountains to the back of the statue, but their location and height do not allow for this line of sight.

It's not really proof, but the photos below show you that the line of sight in your photos is just not possible while not hovering in the air.

https://www.flickr.com/photos/mastababa/30507630257/

https://www.flickr.com/photos/mastababa/30228411940/

https://www.flickr.com/photos/mastababa/25417712997/

Comment: Second one is of Sugarloaf... not the same. That one I did 2 years ago. That last one is really too low to see Rio in back.

Comment: The last one is taken on Rua Sao Clemente, on a point visible in your second picture. The second one from Sugerloaf, which is visible in both your pictures, is to illustrate the line of sight, even though it's not too helpful, as the Christ is covered in clouds in that image.

Comment: Fair demonstration. There does not seem to be a higher point sufficiently close to get this view.